# when rendering an image i get a white box

Tags: rendering

[image]

I am having an issue seeing my scene in the render view, every time I render a blank white box is rendered.

I created the model using the map addon and then added a hdr image for the surface of the background.

How can I get a rendered image?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What are you trying to render? Could you please add an image of your workspace and viewport? Without that, it's just guessing.

Comment: Looks like it's rendering the default cube. Perhaps you've only hidden it in the viewport (eye icon restriction toggle in the outliner) and not in the render (camera icon)?